# How to Obtain ClientID from PlayStation

Tags: oauth-2.0, playstation

I want my users to be able to authenticate using their Playstation account, but how do I obtain a client ID (register application) from Playstation Network/Playstation? I am unable to find any documentation regarding this. Preferably, you want to use Oauth2.